# python subprocess: how to capture if the command fails

Tags: python

Example

I am trying the below

```
try:
    proc=subprocess.Popen(["yt-dlp"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (out, err) = proc.communicate()
    print(f"out: {out}")
    print(f"err: {err}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"exception: {e}")

exitcode = proc.returncode
print(f"exitode: {exitcode}")
```

it gives

```
>>> try:
...     proc=subprocess.Popen(["yt-dlp"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
...     (out, err) = proc.communicate()
...     print(f"out: {out}")
...     print(f"err: {err}")
... except Exception as e:
...     print(f"exception: {e}")
... 

Usage: yt-dlp [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]

yt-dlp: error: You must provide at least one URL.
Type yt-dlp --help to see a list of all options.

out: b''
err: None
>>> exitcode = proc.returncode
>>> print(f"exitode: {exitcode}")
exitode: 2
>>>
```

Q1) Why the below is getting printout out directly to the terminal. I thought it will be stored in variable out.

```
Usage: yt-dlp [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]

yt-dlp: error: You must provide at least one URL.
Type yt-dlp --help to see a list of all options.
```

Q2) also as we see the command failed, how to capture that it failed. Here we dont see any exception raised/

Comment: You only redirect `stdout`. Error messages are typically written to `stderr`.